# Rewrite sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download images path to real image name

Tags: content, images, urlrewriter

I have links to Salesforce Content images which I'm using inside visualforce pages inside a Site, the links have the following path: sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/Image_Id.

I want it to be the name of the image, for example: Image_Name.jpg

There is a way to rewrite those Content url path to real names of images?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue . do you have any idea Solution?